# Get dates with values greater than average borrow rate

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table called `BOOK` (memberId, ISBN, dateBorrowed)
For example:

```
   isbn       |    memberId |   borrowed   
-------+---------------+-------------+----
9998-01-101-9 |             |           
9998-01-101-9 |             |            
9998-01-101-9 |             |            
9998-01-101-9 |        1000 | 2018-10-02
9998-01-101-9 |        1010 | 2018-09-04
9998-01-101-9 |        1021 | 2018-09-14
9998-01-101-9 |             |            
9998-01-101-9 |        1001 | 2018-10-02
```

I have to SELECT all `dates`, where total count of borrowed books per day is larger, than per all days in average. How to do it?

I have selected date and how many times was it picked by:

```
SELECT borrowed, COUNT(*) AS dates 
  FROM BOOK
  WHERE borrowed IS NOT NULL
  GROUP BY borrowed;
```

Another query which was written by me is to count average:

```
SELECT SUM(dates)/COUNT(borrowed) AS average 
  FROM (
    SELECT borrowed, COUNT(*) AS dates 
      FROM BOOKS
      WHERE borrowed IS NOT NULL GROUP BY borrowed
  ) AS average;
```

Now, how to concatenate these two sequels into one clear sequel?

Comment: Welcome to SO. We are here to help, not do your work for you. Show that you put in some effort to solve your own issue.

Comment: By writing a sql query :) What have you tried so far? What went wrong?

Comment: I have selected date and how many times was it picked by:

SELECT borrowed, COUNT(*) AS dates
FROM BOOK
WHERE borrowed IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY borrowed;

Comment: Updated description what I have done.

Answer (score 1):

Using window functions can help you much: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-window.html

[demo: db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=88ab47ae21aa81e387886efb65ae33fd)

**My test data:**

```
isbn             borrowed
9998-01-101-1    2018-08-01
9998-01-101-2    2018-08-01
9998-01-101-3    2018-08-01
9998-01-101-4    2018-08-01
9998-01-101-5    2018-08-01
9998-01-101-1    2018-08-02
9998-01-101-2    2018-08-02
9998-01-101-3    2018-08-02
9998-01-101-4    2018-08-03
9998-01-101-5    2018-08-03
9998-01-101-1    2018-08-04
9998-01-101-2    2018-08-04
9998-01-101-3    2018-08-04
9998-01-101-4    2018-08-04
9998-01-101-5    2018-08-05
9998-01-101-1    2018-08-05
```

**The query:**

```
   SELECT 
        * 
    FROM (
        SELECT 
            *, 
            borrowed_all_time::decimal / COUNT(*) OVER () as avg_borrows_per_day    -- D
        FROM (
            SELECT DISTINCT                                                         -- C
                borrowed,
                COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY borrowed) as borrowed_on_day,           -- A
                COUNT(*) OVER () as borrowed_all_time                               -- B
            FROM book
        )s 
    )s
    WHERE borrowed_on_day > avg_borrows_per_day                                     -- E
```

A: This window function counts the rows per `borrowed` date

B: This window function counts all rows which equals to *count borrows of all time*.

The result so far looks like this:

```
borrowed      borrowed_on_day   borrowed_all_time
2018-08-01    5                 16
2018-08-01    5                 16
2018-08-01    5                 16
2018-08-01    5                 16
2018-08-01    5                 16
2018-08-02    3                 16
2018-08-02    3                 16
2018-08-02    3                 16
2018-08-03    2                 16
2018-08-03    2                 16
2018-08-04    4                 16
2018-08-04    4                 16
2018-08-04    4                 16
2018-08-04    4                 16
2018-08-05    2                 16
2018-08-05    2                 16
```

C: Because we need no duplicates we eliminate them with a `DISTINCT`

D: Counting all rows after eliminating all tied rows gives the count of the distinct days. This dividing *borrows of all time* gives the *average borrows per day*. The `decimal` cast is neccessary. It converts the integer division (`16 / 5 == 3`) into a float division (`16 / 5 == 3.2`)

E: Now we can filter *borrows per current day* > *average borrows per day*.

**The result:**

```
borrowed
2018-08-01
2018-08-04
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks a bit like HW, so windowed functions might be out of bounds.

```
SELECT * 
  FROM (
    SELECT BOOK.*,
           CAST(
           COUNT(1) OVER 
             ( PARTITION BY borrowed
             ) AS FLOAT) cntThatDay,
           CAST(
           SUM(1) OVER() AS FLOAT)/ CAST(
               (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT borrowed)
                  FROM BOOKS 
               ) AS FLOAT) AS totalAverage
      FROM BOOK 
     WHERE borrowed IS NOT NULL
    ) TMP
WHERE cntThatDay >= totalAverage;
```